# Thinkster is it mandatory to repopulate a ref in mongoose, express api design

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am learning to design a node / mongoose api with thinkster pro account. As part of designing traditional blog api, I have to get an Article by get request. I am using a express `param` router middleware to get contents of requested article beforehand like so:

```
router.param('article', function(req, res, next, slug){
    Article.findOne({slug: slug})
        .populate('author')
        .then(function(article){
            if (!article) { return res.sendStatus(404); }
            req.article = article;
            return next();
        }).catch(next);
});
```

I do not have any doubts regarding above snippet. If you notice, I am populating 'author'. However, in the below snippet, the get request callback function is repopulating 'author'.

```
router.get('/:article', auth.optional, function(req,res,next){
    Promise.all([
        req.payload ? User.findById(req.payload.id) : null,
        req.article.populate('author').execPopulate()
    ]).then(function(results){
        var user = results[0];
        return res.json({article: req.article.toJSONFor(user)});
    }).catch(next);
});
```

I removed the line `req.article.populate('author').execPopulate()` from the above snippet, but everything still works fine.

**What am I missing? Why should I re-popupate the `author` for the second time ?**

The Schema:

```
var ArticleSchema = new Schema({
    slug: {type:String, lowercase:true, unique:true},
    title: String,
    description: String,
    body: String,
    tagList:[{type:String}],
    favourtiesCount: {type:Number, default:0},
    author:{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'User'}
}, {timestamps:true});
```

Comment: Odds are that you are simply following an "old" blog post. Some actions of `.populate()` were not possible in earlier releases of mongoose that are now possible. Of course, it's arguable to some extent than even `.populate()` is basically replaced by using [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) in modern MongoDB releases, since the "join" actually happens on the "server" where `.populate()` merely "emulates" this by actually performing multiple queries. Turn on `mongoose.set('debug',true)` for the "gory details". But you should look at `$lookup`.

Comment: Sure, I will look in to it :)

Comment: You might want to re-assess the material you choose to "learn from". If the content is actually that out of date then it's probably not worth what you are paying for it.

Comment: On thinkster class page, It says 'Up to date (Aug '17) ', Plus site has a good reputation with some solid reviews. Its only after the signup I got to know that support is really poor. Anyway, lesson learnt!